# Ruby websocket client for websocket-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am developing a rails webpage which need to use websocket functionality to communicate with an external ruby client. In order to do this, I am using the **websocket-rails** gem in the rails server, definning the client_connected client_disconnected event and a specific action to received the messages from the client (new_message).

On the client side I have tried to use different ruby gems like **faye-websocket-ruby** and **websocket-client-simple** but I always obtain errors when I try to send a message. On the server I can't find the way to process these messages. Both gems has a send method with only accepts a string (not being able to specify the name of the event)

The code that I have been using is the following:

**Server side**

**app/controllers/chat_controller.rb**

```
class ChatController < WebsocketRails::BaseController
  def new_message
    puts ')'*40
  end

  def client_connected
    puts '-'*40
  end

  def client_disconnected
    puts '&'*40
  end
end
```

**config/events.rb**

```
WebsocketRails::EventMap.describe do
  subscribe :client_connected, :to => ChatController, :with_method => :client_connected

  subscribe :message, :to => ChatController, :with_method => :new_message

  subscribe :client_disconnected, :to => ChatController, :with_method => :client_disconnected
end
```

**config/initializers/websocket_rails.rb**

```
WebsocketRails.setup do |config|
  config.log_path = "#{Rails.root}/log/websocket_rails.log"
  config.log_internal_events = true
  config.synchronize = false
end
```

**Client side**

**websocket-client-simple**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'websocket-client-simple'

ws = WebSocket::Client::Simple.connect 'ws://localhost:3000/websocket'

ws.on :message do |msg|
  puts msg.data
end

ws.on :new_message do
  hash = { channel: 'example' }
  ws.send hash
end

ws.on :close do |e|
  p e
  exit 1
end

ws.on :error do |e|
  p e
end

hash = { channel: 'Example', message: 'Example' }
ws.send 'new_message', hash

loop do
  ws.send STDIN.gets.strip
end
```

**faye-websocket**

```
require 'faye/websocket'
require 'eventmachine'

EM.run {
  ws = Faye::WebSocket::Client.new('ws://localhost:3000/websocket')

  ws.on :open do |event|
    p [:open]
  end

  ws.on :message do |event|
    p [:message, event.data]
  end

  ws.on :close do |event|
    p [:close, event.code, event.reason]
    ws = nil
  end

  ws.send( 'Example Text' )
}
```

Thanks in advance. Regards.

PD: Let me know if you need more code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution. The problem was that the message needs to be constructed with a [certain format](https://gist.github.com/DanKnox/5587677) in order to be understood by websocket-rails.

Example: **ws.send( '["new_message",{"data":"Example message"}]' )**

where new_message is the event which websocket-rails is listening to.